# Trouble understanding the computation for Jordan normal form?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I am trying to understand an example of computation of Jordan Normal Form from Jim Hefferon's book "Linear Algebra". The example is given [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBTM7.png). I am a bit confused trying to understand the similarity diagram from the example:

> $\qquad\qquad\qquad $[image]

In the end, he says the computations needed to compute the JNF are:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
 -\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & -1 \\
 1 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & -2 \\
 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

I understand the first and third matrices, but why is it $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & -1 \\
 1 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ and not $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & -1 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$? In the similarity diagram, the upper arrow has $T-3I$written. And $T-3I=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & -1 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$.

Although, computing the following product of matrices, I get:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\
 -\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & -1 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & -2 \\
 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Which is a matrix he mentions previously:

$$\mathtt{Rep}_{B,B}(t-3)=N=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

So I may be doing some silly mistake but am unable to spot it. If someone need the book too, [here it is](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SsnWKG6UJC42ljwDtu75al1u9EQu4G9D/view?usp=sharing), this example is on page 449 in the book or page 459 in the PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find a change of basis matrix $R$ such that $R^{-1} T R$ is in the JNF. The algorithm to find the basis vectors is nicely described in the case of the eigenvalue $0$, so you are really trying to find $R$ such that $R^{-1} (T-3I) R$ is in JCF. But once you find such $R$, you can just apply it to $T$ instead of $T-3I$, because by distributivity of matrix multiplication, $R^{-1} (T-3I) R = R^{-1} T R - 3R^{-1} I R = R^{-1} T R - 3 I$, and so if $R^{-1} (T-3I) R$ is in JNF, so is $R^{-1} T R = R^{-1} (T-3I) R + 3I$.

This also corresponds with your observation that for your matrix choice you got the Jordan cell with zeros on the diagonal, but when you start with the original $T$, you get a Jordan cell with threes on the diagonal.

Comment: Ah, I remember now! He is using something related to [this lemma](https://i.imgur.com/gc3tRb8.png), right?

Comment: Yes, this lemma is very much the point I was trying to make :) I understand your question as "should we use $T-3I$ or $T$ in that sandwich", and then the answer is that it doesn't really matter, because they are related in a very simple way, and while both are meaningful, the later is what gets you the solution of the original problem "find JNF of $T$". So what confused you in the exercise is just jumping one step forward without explicitly stating so.